# API Implementation help and how to do it from begining?

Tags: php, api, label

I do not understand how I present my question here! I am a very much starter on API implementation.

I have a website, where I would like to create a form for my potential client where anyone can enter their web url and email address. Then I need to follow the Steps to implement the usecase:

1) Create Account

You will create a DudaWhite sub-account that is related to your master account with Duda. This sub-account will later grant access to edit the site you create. To do this, we will call the /accounts/create URI to create the account with the input data.

API URL: api.dudamobile.com/api/accounts/create
Parameters:

```
account_name - your sub account users email address (mandatory)
first_name - your sub account users first name (optional)
last_name - your sub account users last name (optional)
```

Success response code: [http_code] => 204

PHP code example:

```
<?php
//Set JSON formated message to send to Duda
$data = '
    {   
      "account_name": "{account_email}", 
      "first_name": "{account_owner_first_name}", 
      "last_name": "{account_owner_last_name}"
    }
';
//Initiate cURL 
$ch = curl_init();
//Set cURL parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/accounts/create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{your_api_username}:{your_api_password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);   
//Perform cURL call and set $output as returned data, if any is returned
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>

2) Create Site

Now that we have the sub-account created, we also want to create a site to grant access to. To do this, we will POST a message to the /sites/create URI.

API URL: https://api.dudamobile.com/api/sites/create
Parameters:

    site_data:
    original_site_url - the base URL of the website you want to convert (mandatory)

Success response code: [http_code] => 200


Success Response: site_name

<?php
//Set JSON formated message to send to Duda
$data = '
    {   
    "site_data":
        {
            "original_site_url":"{original_site_url}"
        }
    }
';
//Initiate cURL 
$ch = curl_init();
//Set cURL parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/sites/create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{your_api_username}:{your_api_password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);   
//Perform cURL call and set $output as returned data, please note the retuned site_name value
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

3) Grant sub-account access

Now that we have the sub-account and site created, we want to grant access for the sub-account to the site.

API URL: https://api.dudamobile.com/api/grantaccess/{account_name}/sites/{site_name}
Parameters:

```
account_name (from the account you created above)
site_name (from the site you created above as well)
```

Success response code: [http_code] => 200

```
<?php
$data = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/accounts/grant-access/{previously_created_account_name}/sites/{previously_created_site_alias}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{your_api_username}:{your_api_password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);   
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

4) Perform Single Sign On

After you’ve created a sub-account for your user, a site and granted access, you can perform SSO to log them directly into your branded editor. Head over to our SSO page to see exactly how to implement this last step.

Note:

```
Sub-account users cannot create or delete sites, this must be done by the DudaWhite partner.
The login, dashboard and editor pages cannot be customized through the API, they need to be customized by logging directly into the partner account and going to the account settings.
```

Single Sign-On (SSO)
Overview

The authentication solution offered by DudaMobile provides a true Single Sign-On user experience. The user will begin by logging in to the DudaWhite Partners Site. Once the login is successful, the user will be able to access the DudaMobile editor without any additional authentication. The Single Sign-On will be achieved using HMAC-SHA1 encryption based on the private key shared between the Partners Site and DudaMobile. Here is the process:

```
The user logs into the Partner's website and clicks on a link to access the mobile editor.
The Partner opens a new browser window/tab (or embeds an IFrame into an existing page), passing the set of predefined parameters (see below) in the URL, including the HMAC-SHA1 based signature.
DudaMobile reads the parameters, validates the HMAC-SHA1 signature, identifies the user and allows the user to work with the tool in the scope of a browser session.
Upon successful login, the user lands up on the page defined within the URL.
```

HMAC-SHA1 authentication details

The security of the authentication solution will be based on the following elements shared by the Partner and DudaMobile:

```
A secret key shared and maintained only between the Partner and DudaMobile.
Set of URL request parameters passed as part of the request redirecting the user to DudaMobile.
HMAC-SHA1 signature encryption logic.
```

Secret Key

```
The secret key will be generated and shared securely between the Partner and DudaMobile. The key can be found inside of your DudaMobile account under the API section.
The security key will be of 128-bit length represented by 32 chars HEX string, i.e. 1a6db9c4f4cc5c870ff813290f961507 or 249ef41fcf9dbc935399296929594b43
DudaMobile reads the parameters, validates the HMAC-SHA1 signature, identifies the user and allows the user to work with the tool in the scope of a browser session.
Upon successful login, the user lands up on the page defined within the URL.
```

Request parameters

When the user is redirected to the DM tool, the URL request must contain the following parameters:

```
Parameter Name  Parameter Type  Description
dm_sig_site     (String)    Site name – the unique site identifier used during site creation
dm_sig_user     (String)    Account name (usually E-Mail) of the sub-user account you are trying to SSO into. This was used during account creation.
dm_sig_partner_key  (6 chars HEX String) i.e. 6d00f     Partner identifier key. This is a unique and secret key to the partner and can be found inside of the dashboard API section.
dm_sig_timestamp    (Number) i.e. 1291050919 equivalent to (2010-11-29 17:15:19Z)   Time at which the signature was generated. The time will be in UNIX time format, i.e. number of seconds elapsed since Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970 (epoch). Used to validate that the signature has not been expired. Make sure you are generating this at time of SSO attempt.
dm_sig  (String)    The HEX string representing the signature value of HMAC-SHA1 encryption. See below of how to generate this value.
Signature validation/generation
```

In order to verify that the request came from the trusted party, the signature generation (your side) and validation (our side) should share the same algorithm logic. To generate/validate the signature:

```
Make a list of all parameters that start with “dm_sig_” sorted in reverse alphabetical order.
Create name/value pair strings for each entry in the list, removing the “dm_sig_”. For example, “dm_sig_site” becomes “site=examplesite_name”
Concatenate all name/value pairs together, to form a string like “…timestamp=1378904651site=examplesite_name…”
Prepend secret key to the beginning of the string.
HMACSHA1 the entire string using the secret key. The result should be sent as the dm_sig parameter.
```

Example:

Given the following parameters, we will construct our SSO attempt:

```
Time Stamp = 1378904651 (should normally be generated at time of SSO request)
Account Name = example@email.com
Site Name = examplesite_name
Secret Key = 5eebe8de321dce05cb6b39fb2d5d9a9d
Partner Key = fA4dSQ
```

The generated signature should match:

4d5a67c25bad09b5da11ef858eb58096d1bcee55

Using all of this information, we can construct our URL that will permit SSO:

http://{editorurl.partnersite.com}/home/site/examplesite_name?dm_sig_partner_key=fA4dSQ&dm_sig_timestamp=1378904651&dm_sig_user=example@email.com&dm_sig_site=examplesite_name&dm_sig=4d5a67c25bad09b5da11ef858eb58096d1bcee55
SSO implementation, in PHP

```
<?php
//Set editor custom domain
$editor_url = '{Your Custom Editor Domain}';
//Set SSO Parameters
$dm_sig_site = '{Site Name you want to Login to}';
$dm_sig_user = '{Account Name you are logging in}';
$dm_sig_partner_key = '{Secret Partner Key}';
$dm_sig_timestamp = date_timestamp_get(date_create());
$secret_key = '{Secret SSO Key}';
//Concatenate sso strings so it can be encrypted
$dm_sig_string = $secret_key.'user='.$dm_sig_user.'timestamp='.$dm_sig_timestamp.'site='.$dm_sig_site.'partner_key='.$dm_sig_partner_key;
//Encrypt values
$dm_sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $dm_sig_string, $secret_key);
//Create SSO link
$sso_link = 'http://'.$editor_url.'/home/site/'.$dm_sig_site.'?dm_sig_partner_key='.$dm_sig_partner_key.'&dm_sig_timestamp='.$dm_sig_timestamp.'&dm_sig_user='.$dm_sig_user.'&dm_sig_site='.$dm_sig_site.'&dm_sig='.$dm_sig;
//Print SSO link
echo $sso_link;
?>
```

My questions are:

1. I created a form on this page: http://designmobisite.com/tour/. Now what I need to do?
2. Would I need to create any php files and then link this form to that or I need to modify my existing php file. Please note my site is a wordpress site.

Please take my apology for this big question and can you help me (step by step) implementing this api.

Comment: "Can you help me (step by step)" - this isn't really how Stack Overflow works. It is better for you to ask a specific question about where you are stuck, otherwise someone will have to spend hours of their time assisting you. If you need that level of support, you may need to engage a freelancer.

Comment: Sorry, you really want to tell us that you have next to no knowledge on php, you copied all that code above from somewhere and want to sell that to a potential customer of yours? And you want us to do all your work? Hm...

Comment: Hello both, Thanks for your reply. Just to let you know, I do have some php knowledge and the platform I am using to create mobile website I do not need to know any coding at all. They are just drag and drop based. My question was mainly how to start! Do I need to create a new php page or I need to modify my existing template to implement this api coding. I copied from somewhere, because I wanted to give you a good idea. Yes, I can hire a freelancer yet I can do this if I get a little bit starting point from you guys. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AnamAhmed can you share how did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

use below link to implement Duda White API Plugin

https://support.dudamobile.com/01DudaMobile/How-To/DudaAPI_and_DudaWhite_with_WordPress

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. It is a best practice to answer the question with text and not only with a URL. ULR content can change with time.